# What should be principal id while assigning role access to App?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

By Terraform I have to do a role assignment to storage account and assign access to an application (which is created by app registration and have API permission of Azure Storage)

But when I am defining role assignment as

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "storage_app_access_new" {
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
  principal_id         = module.ad_application.id
  scope                = module.storage_account.id
}
```

The `apply` command is hanging for longer time without error. I am suspecting the issue is with principal id can you help?

Comment: What is type/value of `module.ad_application`, could you provide some context? In addition you could set the environment variable `TF_LOG=DEBUG` to get addtional feedback.

Comment: Please check for the answer if helpful to you. Then you can sign it as a correct one to benefit others who meet the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `object ID`, not the `application ID`.

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "storage_app_access_new" {
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
  principal_id         = module.ad_application.object_id
  scope                = module.storage_account.id
}
```

I don't know what you have in that module, so I cannot tell if it has the key like this. You need to check how to get the object ID from that module.

With the az cli you would get it like this:

```
az ad sp show --id <app-id> --query objectId -o tsv
```